# 'select' listener in xtype combo, scope issue with IF?

Tags: javascript, listener, openlayers, extjs3, geoext

I wonder if this is a problem of scope. The thing is that I select an option in a `xtype combo` (extjs3.4) and that selection at first can be read outside and inside an `if` section (attached image). Now, when I select another option, that selection is only read outside the `if` section (ie. it's not read inside it). Is this a normal problem of scope? if so, how could I solve it?

[image]

```
listeners: {
  'select': function(combo, record) {
    var comboLayer = this.getValue();
    var rawLayer = this.getRawValue();
    var loadedLayers = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < mapPanel.map.layers.length; i++) {
      loadedLayers.push(mapPanel.map.layers[i].name);
    }
    console.log('outsideIf: ' + loadedLayers);
    console.log('outsideIf: ' + rawLayer);
    console.log('outsideIf: ' + comboLayer);
    if (loadedLayers.indexOf(rawLayer) > -1) {
      console.log('insideIf: ' + loadedLayers);
      console.log('insideIf: ' + rawLayer);
      console.log('insideIf: ' + comboLayer);
      newUrl = '/pg?layers=' + comboLayer;
      protocol.options.url = newUrl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for. But from code above I could say, that console output is valid. In `if` you check if `[Google Hybrid, Cold seeps, info]` contains respectively `Cold seeps` and `Borehloes`. First exists in array, second no.

Comment: @Lolo thanks for the reply, I just need an `else` to check that my code was doing the right thing, so it's solved, thanks anyway Lolo.